# Convert string to VKCode: Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'string'

Tags: delphi, switch-statement, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying convert a string to VKCode using [this](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,23179.msg138071.html#msg138071) reference, but when try compile, comes the following error's:

> E2001 Ordinal type required

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'string'

This means that `case (expression) of` not is a option to be used here?

```
function VKStringToWord(const aVKstring: string): Word;
begin
  if aVKstring = '' then
    Exit(0);
  case UpperCase(aVKstring) of
    'VK_A':
      Result := $41;
  else
    Result := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you cannot use `case` with strings. According to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Case_Statements):

> `selectorExpression` is any expression of an **ordinal type**

(emphasis mine). Strings are not ordinal types.

What you can do, however, is something like this:

```pascal
function VKStringToWord(const AVKString: string): Word;
const
  Data: array[0..192] of record
    Key: string;
    Val: Word
  end =
    (
      (Key: 'VK_0'                   ; Val: $30),
      (Key: 'VK_1'                   ; Val: $31),
      (Key: 'VK_2'                   ; Val: $32),
      (Key: 'VK_3'                   ; Val: $33),
      (Key: 'VK_4'                   ; Val: $34),
      (Key: 'VK_5'                   ; Val: $35),
      (Key: 'VK_6'                   ; Val: $36),
      (Key: 'VK_7'                   ; Val: $37),
      (Key: 'VK_8'                   ; Val: $38),
      (Key: 'VK_9'                   ; Val: $39),
      (Key: 'VK_A'                   ; Val: $41),
      (Key: 'VK_ACCEPT'              ; Val: 30),
      (Key: 'VK_ADD'                 ; Val: 107),
      (Key: 'VK_APPS'                ; Val: $5D),
      (Key: 'VK_ATTN'                ; Val: $F6),
      (Key: 'VK_B'                   ; Val: $42),
      (Key: 'VK_BACK'                ; Val: 8),
      (Key: 'VK_BROWSER_BACK'        ; Val: $A6),
      (Key: 'VK_BROWSER_FAVORITES'   ; Val: $AB),
      (Key: 'VK_BROWSER_FORWARD'     ; Val: $A7),
      (Key: 'VK_BROWSER_HOME'        ; Val: $AC),
      (Key: 'VK_BROWSER_REFRESH'     ; Val: $A8),
      (Key: 'VK_BROWSER_SEARCH'      ; Val: $AA),
      (Key: 'VK_BROWSER_STOP'        ; Val: $A9),
      (Key: 'VK_C'                   ; Val: $43),
      (Key: 'VK_CANCEL'              ; Val: 3),
      (Key: 'VK_CAPITAL'             ; Val: 20),
      (Key: 'VK_CLEAR'               ; Val: 12),
      (Key: 'VK_CONTROL'             ; Val: 17),
      (Key: 'VK_CONVERT'             ; Val: 28),
      (Key: 'VK_CRSEL'               ; Val: $F7),
      (Key: 'VK_D'                   ; Val: $44),
      (Key: 'VK_DECIMAL'             ; Val: 110),
      (Key: 'VK_DELETE'              ; Val: 46),
      (Key: 'VK_DIVIDE'              ; Val: 111),
      (Key: 'VK_DOWN'                ; Val: 40),
      (Key: 'VK_E'                   ; Val: $45),
      (Key: 'VK_END'                 ; Val: 35),
      (Key: 'VK_EREOF'               ; Val: $F9),
      (Key: 'VK_ESCAPE'              ; Val: 27),
      (Key: 'VK_EXECUTE'             ; Val: 43),
      (Key: 'VK_EXSEL'               ; Val: $F8),
      (Key: 'VK_F'                   ; Val: $46),
      (Key: 'VK_F1'                  ; Val: 112),
      (Key: 'VK_F10'                 ; Val: 121),
      (Key: 'VK_F11'                 ; Val: 122),
      (Key: 'VK_F12'                 ; Val: 123),
      (Key: 'VK_F13'                 ; Val: 124),
      (Key: 'VK_F14'                 ; Val: 125),
      (Key: 'VK_F15'                 ; Val: 126),
      (Key: 'VK_F16'                 ; Val: 127),
      (Key: 'VK_F17'                 ; Val: 128),
      (Key: 'VK_F18'                 ; Val: 129),
      (Key: 'VK_F19'                 ; Val: 130),
      (Key: 'VK_F2'                  ; Val: 113),
      (Key: 'VK_F20'                 ; Val: 131),
      (Key: 'VK_F21'                 ; Val: 132),
      (Key: 'VK_F22'                 ; Val: 133),
      (Key: 'VK_F23'                 ; Val: 134),
      (Key: 'VK_F24'                 ; Val: 135),
      (Key: 'VK_F3'                  ; Val: 114),
      (Key: 'VK_F4'                  ; Val: 115),
      (Key: 'VK_F5'                  ; Val: 116),
      (Key: 'VK_F6'                  ; Val: 117),
      (Key: 'VK_F7'                  ; Val: 118),
      (Key: 'VK_F8'                  ; Val: 119),
      (Key: 'VK_F9'                  ; Val: 120),
      (Key: 'VK_FINAL'               ; Val: 24),
      (Key: 'VK_G'                   ; Val: $47),
      (Key: 'VK_H'                   ; Val: $48),
      (Key: 'VK_HANGUL'              ; Val: 21),
      (Key: 'VK_HANJA'               ; Val: 25),
      (Key: 'VK_HELP'                ; Val: 47),
      (Key: 'VK_HIGHESTVALUE'        ; Val: $FFFF),
      (Key: 'VK_HOME'                ; Val: 36),
      (Key: 'VK_I'                   ; Val: $49),
      (Key: 'VK_INSERT'              ; Val: 45),
      (Key: 'VK_J'                   ; Val: $4A),
      (Key: 'VK_JUNJA'               ; Val: 23),
      (Key: 'VK_K'                   ; Val: $4B),
      (Key: 'VK_KANA'                ; Val: 21),
      (Key: 'VK_KANJI'               ; Val: 25),
      (Key: 'VK_L'                   ; Val: $4C),
      (Key: 'VK_LAUNCH_APP1'         ; Val: $B6),
      (Key: 'VK_LAUNCH_APP2'         ; Val: $B7),
      (Key: 'VK_LAUNCH_MAIL'         ; Val: $B4),
      (Key: 'VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT' ; Val: $B5),
      (Key: 'VK_LBUTTON'             ; Val: 1),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_ALT'             ; Val: 18),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_AT'              ; Val: $103),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_BACKSLASH'       ; Val: $DC),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_CALL'            ; Val: $101),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_CAPSLOCK'        ; Val: 20),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_CLOSE_BRAKET'    ; Val: $DD),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_COMMA'           ; Val: $BC),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_ENDCALL'         ; Val: $102),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_EQUAL'           ; Val: $BB),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_LALT'            ; Val: $A4),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_MINUS'           ; Val: $BD),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_OPEN_BRAKET'     ; Val: $DB),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_POINT'           ; Val: $BE),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_POWER'           ; Val: $100),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_QUOTE'           ; Val: $DE),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_RALT'            ; Val: $A5),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_SEMI_COMMA'      ; Val: $BA),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_SLASH'           ; Val: $BF),
      (Key: 'VK_LCL_TILDE'           ; Val: $C0),
      (Key: 'VK_LCONTROL'            ; Val: $A2),
      (Key: 'VK_LEFT'                ; Val: 37),
      (Key: 'VK_LMENU'               ; Val: $A4),
      (Key: 'VK_LSHIFT'              ; Val: $A0),
      (Key: 'VK_LWIN'                ; Val: $5B),
      (Key: 'VK_M'                   ; Val: $4D),
      (Key: 'VK_MBUTTON'             ; Val: 4),
      (Key: 'VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK'    ; Val: $B0),
      (Key: 'VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE'    ; Val: $B3),
      (Key: 'VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK'    ; Val: $B1),
      (Key: 'VK_MEDIA_STOP'          ; Val: $B2),
      (Key: 'VK_MENU'                ; Val: 18),
      (Key: 'VK_MODECHANGE'          ; Val: 31),
      (Key: 'VK_MULTIPLY'            ; Val: 106),
      (Key: 'VK_N'                   ; Val: $4E),
      (Key: 'VK_NEXT'                ; Val: 34),
      (Key: 'VK_NONAME'              ; Val: $FC),
      (Key: 'VK_NONCONVERT'          ; Val: 29),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMLOCK'             ; Val: $90),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD0'             ; Val: 96),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD1'             ; Val: 97),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD2'             ; Val: 98),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD3'             ; Val: 99),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD4'             ; Val: 100),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD5'             ; Val: 101),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD6'             ; Val: 102),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD7'             ; Val: 103),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD8'             ; Val: 104),
      (Key: 'VK_NUMPAD9'             ; Val: 105),
      (Key: 'VK_O'                   ; Val: $4F),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_1'               ; Val: $BA),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_102'             ; Val: $E2),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_2'               ; Val: $BF),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_3'               ; Val: $C0),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_4'               ; Val: $DB),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_5'               ; Val: $DC),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_6'               ; Val: $DD),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_7'               ; Val: $DE),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_8'               ; Val: $DF),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_CLEAR'           ; Val: $FE),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_COMMA'           ; Val: $BC),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_MINUS'           ; Val: $BD),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_PERIOD'          ; Val: $BE),
      (Key: 'VK_OEM_PLUS'            ; Val: $BB),
      (Key: 'VK_P'                   ; Val: $50),
      (Key: 'VK_PA1'                 ; Val: $FD),
      (Key: 'VK_PAUSE'               ; Val: 19),
      (Key: 'VK_PLAY'                ; Val: $FA),
      (Key: 'VK_PRINT'               ; Val: 42),
      (Key: 'VK_PRIOR'               ; Val: 33),
      (Key: 'VK_PROCESSKEY'          ; Val: $E7),
      (Key: 'VK_Q'                   ; Val: $51),
      (Key: 'VK_R'                   ; Val: $52),
      (Key: 'VK_RBUTTON'             ; Val: 2),
      (Key: 'VK_RCONTROL'            ; Val: $A3),
      (Key: 'VK_RETURN'              ; Val: 13),
      (Key: 'VK_RIGHT'               ; Val: 39),
      (Key: 'VK_RMENU'               ; Val: $A5),
      (Key: 'VK_RSHIFT'              ; Val: $A1),
      (Key: 'VK_RWIN'                ; Val: $5C),
      (Key: 'VK_S'                   ; Val: $53),
      (Key: 'VK_SCROLL'              ; Val: $91),
      (Key: 'VK_SELECT'              ; Val: 41),
      (Key: 'VK_SEPARATOR'           ; Val: 108),
      (Key: 'VK_SHIFT'               ; Val: 16),
      (Key: 'VK_SLEEP'               ; Val: $5F),
      (Key: 'VK_SNAPSHOT'            ; Val: 44),
      (Key: 'VK_SPACE'               ; Val: 32),
      (Key: 'VK_SUBTRACT'            ; Val: 109),
      (Key: 'VK_T'                   ; Val: $54),
      (Key: 'VK_TAB'                 ; Val: 9),
      (Key: 'VK_U'                   ; Val: $55),
      (Key: 'VK_UNDEFINED'           ; Val: $FF),
      (Key: 'VK_UNKNOWN'             ; Val: 0),
      (Key: 'VK_UP'                  ; Val: 38),
      (Key: 'VK_V'                   ; Val: $56),
      (Key: 'VK_VOLUME_DOWN'         ; Val: $AE),
      (Key: 'VK_VOLUME_MUTE'         ; Val: $AD),
      (Key: 'VK_VOLUME_UP'           ; Val: $AF),
      (Key: 'VK_W'                   ; Val: $57),
      (Key: 'VK_X'                   ; Val: $58),
      (Key: 'VK_XBUTTON1'            ; Val: 5),
      (Key: 'VK_XBUTTON2'            ; Val: 6),
      (Key: 'VK_Y'                   ; Val: $59),
      (Key: 'VK_Z'                   ; Val: $5A),
      (Key: 'VK_ZOOM'                ; Val: $FB)
    );
begin

  for var VK in Data do
    if SameText(VK.Key, AVKString) then
      Exit(VK.Val);

  Result := 0;

end;
```

Comment: Fwiw, while I was doing commercial Delphi development, I never really felt any burning need for any of the post-D7 language changes apart from Unicode support, especially not generics or enhanced RTTI, etc.  Otoh, string-case support would give the biggest single increase in practical expressive power and concision the language could have.  Imo, ymmv, etc ...